# How would I create this pattern to wrap around a cylinder?

Tags: texturing

How would I create this pattern to wrap around a cylinder to be 3D printed?

[image]

Comment: You can model a segment, then array and use a Simple Deform modifier (Bend mode) in order to make it circular

Comment: OK, I am pretty much a beginner.
How do I even model a segment, tried with a UV Sphere but that didnt work.

Answer (score 2):

Use your image as *Reference* image, create a mesh that follow the shapes:

[image]

Move some vertices forwards in order to create the 3D relief:

[image]

Use an *Array* modifier to repeat:

[image]

Use a *Simple Deform* modifier in *Bend* mode, 360° on Z, to makethe shape circular, etc:

[image]